# Making an array in Linux, using bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Assume that the Pid of active processes on my machines are  1000 and 2000. 
I am trying to make an array in Linux such that

The command  `echo ${Pid_Current[0]}`    gives 1000 in output

The command  `echo ${Pid_Current[1]}`    gives 2000 in output

Here is my code:

```
declare -a Pid_Current 

Pid_Current=$(ps -aF | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}')
```

However, instead of the desired output I explained above, I receive the following output:

`echo ${Pid_Current[0]}`    gives  1000 2000  in output

`echo ${Pid_Current[1]}`    gives nothing in output

Would you please advise me what part of my code is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash array assignment is done by enclosing the expression in parenthesis, so to use array assignment you need to write:

```
Pid_Current=($(ps -aF | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}'))
```

Without parenthesis the result of the expression is assigned to `Pid_Current[0]`